# Getting records through parentID from CategoryCollection in Typo3

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I am using `CategoryCollection` to get the records of a specific category ID, but the problem is it only loads the exact category for e.g I have `parent > child` and I have attached child category ID to a record and I select child category, then it shows me the record fine, but if I select parentID, then it does not show the child category record.

```
$collection = \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Category\Collection\CategoryCollection::load(
        $categoryID,
        true,
        'tx_myextension_table_name',
        'categories'
    );
```

Is there any built-in way to get the records of all child category if I select parent ID from `CategoryCollection`or do I have to write something custom for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no built-in solution for complex selections like this. You will indeed need to write your own logic which could work like this:

1. Find categories whose `parent` is your category
2. Repeat this recursively for every category found until you don't find any children for each category anymore
3. Do a custom `IN()` query with the list of category UIDs

If you have deep category trees, the list of category UIDs could be put in a [custom cache](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/8.7/ApiOverview/CachingFramework/). You can use the root category UID or a hash thereof as key. These cache entries should be [tagged](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/8.7/ApiOverview/CachingFramework/Architecture/Index.html#about-tags) with `sys_category`. Alternatively you can add a `sys_category_<uid>` tag for every category UID in your list. This ensures that whenever something changes about one of the categories, the cache entries are dropped and you can rebuild the list.